# Same action with 2 errors: TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1 vs TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. typescript + redux toolkit

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I met a very weird problem, calling the action created by createSlice returns 2 conflicting errors:

```
export interface UffStatusState {
  fetchingPickStatus: APIState;
  activeMerchant: string | null;
  displayPicker: boolean | false;
}

const uffStatusSlice = createSlice({
  name: "uffStatus",
  initialState: {
    fetchingPickStatus: APIState.idle,
    activeMerchant: null,
    displayPicker: false,
  } as UffStatusState,
  reducers: {
    setfetchingPickStatus: (state, fetchingAction: PayloadAction<APIState>) => {
      state.fetchingPickStatus = fetchingAction.payload;
    },
    setActiveMerchant: (state, activeMerchantAction: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.activeMerchant = activeMerchantAction.payload;
    },
    setDisplayPicker: (state, display: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
      state.displayPicker = display.payload
    },
  }
});

export const { setfetchingPickStatus, setActiveMerchant, setDisplayPicker } = uffStatusSlice.actions;
export default uffStatusSlice.reducer;
```

Here are the 2 conflicting errors when calling the action with no parameter:

> ERROR in src/components/HeaderBar.tsx:14:56 TS2554: Expected 0
> arguments, but got 1.
> 12 |
> 13 | export default function HeaderBar() {
>
> > 14 |   const handleSelectMerchants = () => useStoreDispatch(setDisplayPicker());
> > |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > 15 |   return (
> > 16 |     <>
> > 17 |       <KatRow className={'header'}>
>
> ERROR in src/components/HeaderBar.tsx:14:56 TS2554: Expected 1
> arguments, but got 0.
> 12 |
> 13 | export default function HeaderBar() {
>
> > 14 |   const handleSelectMerchants = () => useStoreDispatch(setDisplayPicker());
> > |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > 15 |   return (
> > 16 |     <>
> > 17 |       <KatRow className={'header'}>

Calling it with parameter, it returns one error:

> ERROR in src/components/HeaderBar.tsx:14:56 TS2554: Expected 0
> arguments, but got 1.
> 12 |
> 13 | export default function HeaderBar() {
>
> > 14 |   const handleSelectMerchants = () => useStoreDispatch(setDisplayPicker(true));
> > |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > 15 |   return (
> > 16 |     <>
> > 17 |       <KatRow className={'header'}>
>
> ERROR in src/components/MerchantSelection.tsx:64:42 TS2554: Expected 0
> arguments, but got 1.
> 62 | }
> 63 |
>
> > 64 | const onDismiss = () => useStoreDispatch(setDisplayPicker(false));
> > |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > 65 |
> > 66 | export default function MerchantSelection() {
> > 67 |   const { displayPicker } = useStoreSelector( (state) => state.uffStoreSetting );

Answer (score 0):

This *seems* to work if you test it out in a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwMZQKYEMaoMoBthKoA0cACugJ64ToAmAgkjMBAHYC+cAZlBCHAHIAAmloBXAB4ArAM4B6GBAi4A1sBgCAUJtSsx-eqQCS2GJlSI4wWrgvttqCZFhXWWKF3SE4AVS5dTTDEZQKxETThuVBgkAAtgVgBzUgIVUOCALjhDEzMsAG4IuC9mADdUAFlUKDj0NyyZGCgExLgAHzg9XFxCyNpgGTBcShSkFWqsgCMlWzr27nRcGVRC+00kNka4MX90kPxvAF44FAwsPAJUAAoEItZ0EFQsgCIdgLzg56IihPVgRdCT3CkUiXGicRaozSHxkWRygIAdNZbN8QcUmMBylUarE6jAsl1cKiQf1BsMKFCJgslsQipx0DJfLsYYDiaIxIQoLDgSDljAwTF4kkoXssldGuYSAKIUlGMw2FlyFQaAwMWwADzwvKoAB8AEo4IcdTy0RKsAjpULkqk9oaooKWnKWKwEWBKNQ6L0QexiZE+U6sdVavU4OLtSQSpjKkHcW4nQqyO6VfHWOrGs0kvrDcbbmi-dqEZHAzi8Xai9GS3G1S63crPUVIj6G3A+QARAZDEapKlhyVwUmdiiKpN0FPq6bKDCsLNGk28gsD8mUqB2xeUV0j2jNpuNzTsPWFHROaDwDasLYIFvRS2Qm0wkj+jHF4MwB-RdtkrtjapwTjHN57BchCFtWMiFI4zjwLQqCeGIuDwABLIHKgCLspyh5th2S7dlAVxNGIqB6pochyHAQgwDIAC0EGoEw1FQLwUCaJhn4UjhVx6kAA)

Do you have any uncommon settings in your `tsconfig.json`? Is `strict` set to `true`?

Edit:
Your error is actually something else. You have to `const dispatch = useStoreDispatch()` first somewhere in your component and later use that dispatch with `dispatch(setDisplayPicker(true))`

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "test/unit-tests"]
}

Comment: I tried removing strict, it showed same error.

Comment: You should definitely have strict on, just wanted to make sure. 

Your error is actually something else. You have to `const dispatch = useStoreDispatch()` first somewhere in your component and later use that dispatch with `dispatch(setDisplayPicker(true))`